# The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application in Angular

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to Register Angular Application with Azure AD for login. Although i have added redirect URL in my both configuration of the code and in Azure portal. But i still get this error "The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application:"

Below is the screen shot of Azure AD Application configuration

[image]

Below is the configuration of Angular file

```
 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxAdalModule.forRoot({
      tenant: `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`,
      clientId: `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`,
      redirectUri: `https://localhost:4200/frameRedirect.html`, 
      postLogoutRedirectUri: `https://localhost:4200/frameRedirect.html`,
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    }),
  ]
```

Comment: try to add a '/' at the end of the registered url on azure ad

Comment: Are you completely sure the `clientId` matches the client ID of the app registration in your screenshot?

Comment: yes.. i have crossed check it multiple times.. its same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

by adding tick resolved my issue, i had removed tick and added single quotes by mistake

for e.g. [image: redirectUri: <code>frameRedirect.html</code>]

Comment: Feel free to mark this as answer so that others can more easily find the solution.